# At times or in times?

Tags: prepositions

In the example below which preposition is appropriate in or at?

Family will be there for you [at/in] the most difficult times no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Family will be there for you **at** the most difficult times no matter what.

In phrases referencing time, *at* would be the best choice. But in this example, *times* can refer to time or events.

You might use *in* if you mean events:

> Family will be there for you **in** the most difficult situations no matter what.

However, in your original phrase, *during* would be a better preposition to use, since a time span is implied.

> Family will be there for you **during** the most difficult times no matter what.